# Undefined method `between' for Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a URL:

```
xxxx/xxx?status=2
```

I got the value of the `:status` parameter from the URL, converted it to integer, and tried to use `between` method on it:

```
params[:status].to_i.between.(0, 3)
```

but I get the error as below:

```
undefined method `between' for 1:Fixnum
```

I checked the class ancestors:

```
params[:status].to_i.class.ancestors
# => [Fixnum, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Fixnum, Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

I can see `Comparable`, so I don't get why I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mistake in method name: not `between` but `between?`

```
params[:status].to_i.between?(0, 3)
```

Check [Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F).